# Microsoft Access time formatting

Tags: ms-access, time-format

Could someone help with the correct time formatting.
I am using Microsoft Access for 365 installed in the PC (64bit version)

The time is comming from a linked server as military format with the exception of middnigh or passed midnight the format comes as 1000 (without the 2 digits at the begining) (instead of 001000 or 241000) (see pics)
So I'm trying to format in a way the is a easier visual as 00:10:00 or 24:10:00

Thank you before hand for any help

Example
[Link image](https://postimg.cc/7G7bBnc1)

This is the format for time desired

[Image link](https://postimg.cc/bZJ51CD5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TimeSerial` to convert your "numerical" time to true time values:

```
TrueTime = TimeSerial(NumTime \ 10000, NumTime \ 100 Mod 100, NumTime Mod 100)
```

Then apply the format to this as you like.

Comment: Thank You So much this worked like a charm.
A couple or coworker were wondering what the \ 10000 means if it is not dividing

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered. The _backslash_ performs an integer division rounding down. Thus, for example, `245210 \ 10000` returns `24` with no decimals.